# Facebook login process for iOS apps made in Flash AIR?

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I'm getting my head around using Facebook login on iOS apps made in AIR. I have a class I bought, which takes care of Facebook auth stuff, and have got it working, but I'm concerned about the safety of it.

I also have a web app that successfully uses FB login. I store the user's FB id in my database so that when they log in, I can connect them to their user data on my site, just as I would if they used a username/pass.

Comparing my web app Facebook login process to iOS:

WEB APP:

1. User clicks 'log in with Facebook'.
2. Facebook tells my *server* the user is indeed logged in, and returns their Facebook ID, which I search for in my system, and if found, log them into my site - all secure as it's server-side.

iOS:

1. User clicks 'log in with Facebook'.
2. Facebook tells my *app* the user is logged in, and returns their Facebook ID (no longer server-side)
3. My app sends my server the user's Facebook ID, my server searches for it in my system, and if found, logs them in

The iOS way seems vulnerable to someone hacking your app and sending you any old Facebook ID to log into your system with, which can't really happen with the web app login process above.

Your thoughts? How should FB login be done on iOS?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: if you are looked in to facebookSDK for iOS then in sample Folder Facebook given sample example of most using in ios Development. please take a look **SessionLoginSample** how did work and how to impliment.

Comment: You could validate the access token with Facebook server side in step 3.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm using Flash AIR to make the iOS app, so I don't think the facebook SDK for iOS applies. There's an ActionScript 3 SDK for Facebook, but I don't think it works with iOS or Android.

Comment: So is the process the same as for a web app? Facebook checks to see if user is logged in and has authorized your app, and if so returns a token to the return url you state, which you code to log the user into your database with their Facebook ID?